# rails link_to image rather than root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox, dynamic-linking, link-to

I have a fancy box gallery on an index page.  The gallery consists of the instance @gallery which is a model for all images that are supposed to be in the gallery.  The gallery shows once a link is clicked.

I also have three studios on that specific page that I would like to add to the gallery.  Obviously a studio is a different model.  Right now I can get it to where if I click on one of these three studio images, it will open up the fancybox gallery (and will be associated with all of the gallery images because of the :rel => "studio_images" and :class => "grouped_elements").

Right now here in my code for the three studios, I have it linking to the root path but would like those links to link to the image itself:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(studio.image_url.to_s), root_path, :class => "studio_image grouped_elements", :rel => "studio_images" %><br>
```

Is there a way rather than saying root_path I can say something like:

studio.image_url.to_s_path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - interpolate it:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(studio.image_url.to_s), studio.image_url.to_s, :class => "studio_image grouped_elements", :rel => "studio_images" %><br>
```

Comment: great, that works, now my issue is that the studio images are not the same sizeas the rest of the fancybox gallery images